# Reactjs firebase firestore get data from collection filter by currentUser.id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

hi i want to get all data from menus collection by   user.uid.

with my code i can retrieve the last data but not all with this code and i want to know why it just retrieves the last one record and not all of the user's connected thank you in advance for your help

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    console.log("userId", user.uid)
    firebase.firestore().collection('menus').doc(user.uid)
    .get()
    .then(response => {
      console.log("menus",response.data())
     
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // setError(error);
    });

  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show some data that you'd expect/like this code to log that isn't being logged?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  I manage to retrieve the data from the menus collection but I receive that the last record of the connected user or I have several records for the connected user I manage to retrieve the data from the menus collection but I receive that the last record of the user connected or I have several records for the user connected and I need all the data of the connection filtered by uid from the 'user